# Is there a way to configure which unsafe Groovy operations to allow?

Tags: groovy, type-safety

Groovy allows various non-type safe operations that would be allowed in Java at compile time (and sometime runtime).

For example, assigning a list to an array is allowed:

```
Integer[] a = [1, 3]
```

So is assigning an int to a string.

```
String s = 3
```

And you can call a method with the wrong number of arguments and it will compile but will fail at runtime.

You can disallow all of this with the use of the annotation @CompileStatic but is there a way to disallow certain unsafe operations while allowing others?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you rightfully mentioned one should use `@CompileStatic` / `@TypeChecked` to allow for java-like strong typing, and `@CompileDynamic` / `@TypeChecked( SKIP )` to allow for weak typing.

The main question here is how and where to apply those. You can put the annotation on class or method level.

You can define the whole class (meaning all methods) to be type-safe, but make an exception for the specific one:

```
@CompileStatic
class TypeSafe {

  doSafe(){}

  doSafe2(){}

  @CompileDynamic
  doUnsafe(){}

}
```

You can also go the other way around. Leave all class's methods unsafe by default and declare 1 to be type-safe:

```
class TypeSafe {

  doUnsafeSafe(){}

  doUnsafeSafe2(){}

  @CompileStatic
  doUnsafe(){}

}
```